# How to retrieve mfa_serial from config file in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

In my ~/.aws/config file I have:

```
[dev]
region = us-east-1
output = json
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::1111:mfa/user
```

How do I retrieve that mfa_serial from the config in boto3 so I don't have to specify the arn in the py script?

```
sts = session.client('sts')
mfa_code = input("Enter the MFA code: ")
mfa_session = sts.get_session_token(
    DurationSeconds=3600,
    SerialNumber=mfa_serial,
    TokenCode=mfa_code
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the mfa_serial defined in the current config file using botocore.session.get_scoped_config

```
from botocore.session import Session
Session().get_scoped_config().get('mfa_serial')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay getting username input you can get the MFA arn programmatically using `list_mfa_devices`.

This snippet requests the User's IAM name and then retrieves the MFA information.

```
import boto3

iam = session.client('iam')
user = input("Username: ")
response = iam.list_mfa_devices(UserName=user)['MFADevices']
mfa = next(iter(response))['SerialNumber']
print(mfa)
```

The output will be this format:

> arn:aws:iam::123456789123:mfa/amandahugginkiss

**References**

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_mfa_devices

Comment: But that means that you have already created a session using your MFA